# соединить строки разных файлов, при условии что файл источник один, а редактируемых файлов несколько

Tags: shell, sed

есть 20 файлов - 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt .... 20.txt с **разным** кол-вом строк (общее кол-во строк во всех 20 ти файлах 36 тысяч)

и есть один большой файл также с 36 000 строк - big.txt

Задача:
подставить строки из большого файла в начало строк всех 20 файлов

пример:

в большом файле строки:

- привет дядя ваня;
- пока дядя ваня;
- здравствуй дядя ваня;

....и тд.

в 20ти файлах строки:

- милиция хорошо
- полиция хорошо
- пожарники хорошо

...и тд.

в результате в 20ти файлах должно быть:

- привет дядя ваня;милиция хорошо
- пока дядя ваня;полиция хорошо
- здравствуй дядя ваня;пожарники хорошо

...и тд.

доп условие объединять эти 20 файлов нельзя

-------\-----\--------
протестил , получается так:

```
-строка из big.txt;первая строка файла 01.txt
-строка из big.txt;вторая строка файла 01.txt
-....
-строка из big.txt;предпоследняя строка файла 01.txt
-строка из big.txt;последняя строка файла 01.txtперваястрока файла 02.txt
-строка из big.txt;вторая строка файла 02.txt
-строка из big.txt;третья строка файла 02.txt
-....
-строка из big.txt;предпоследняя строка файла 02.txt
-строка из big.txt;последняя строка файла 02.txtперваястрока файла 03.txt
-строка из big.txt;вторая строка файла 03.txt
-строка из big.txt;третья строка файла 03.txt
-....
```

Comment: А вы не хотите эту задачу решать скажем на perl, он как то больше подходит для такого

Answer (score 1, accepted):

во-первых, с помощью программы *sed* описанное вами сделать довольно затруднительно: понадобится весьма длинная и нетривильная программа.

во-вторых, чтобы было проще работать с последовательностью файлов, лучше привести их имена к «нормальному» числовому формату, чтобы количество цифр в названии было аналогичным. т.е., добавить `0` в начало имени `1.txt` и получить `01.txt` (и т.д.):

```
$ for f in [0-9].txt; do mv $f 0$f; done
```

---

### приступим

1. создадим с помощью программы *paste* один большой файл, в котором *все* строки будут объединены так, как вам требуется — разделённые символом `;`:

   ```
   $ paste -d ';' big.txt <(sed '$a\' [0-9][0-9].txt) > newbig.txt
   ```
2. разобъём этот файл на части, содержащие по столько же строк, как и в исходных маленьких файлах:

   1. сохраняем общее количество строк в переменной:

      ```
      $ s=$(sed '$a\' big.txt | wc -l)
      ```
   2. генерируем строку с очень длинной командой (можете посмотреть на её содержимое после генерации командой `echo $p` — это последовательность вызовов *tee*, *head* и *tail*):

      ```
      $ p=$(for f in [0-9][0-9].txt; do n=$(sed '$a\' $f | wc -l); echo -n "| tee >(head -n $n > new$f) | tail -n $((s-n)) "; done)
      ```
   3. интерпретируем с помощью встроенной команды *eval* эту сгенерированную строку (с небольшой добавкой):

      ```
      $ eval "sed '\$a\' newbig.txt $p >/dev/null"
      ```

теперь у вас должны появиться файлы `new01.txt`...`new20.txt` с требующимся вам содержимым.

---

при необходимости повторения тех же операций можно поместить четыре команды, приведённые в пунктах 1 и 2, в файл, и запускать этот файл, не вводя каждую команду по отдельности.

---

### дополнение по поводу слияния последней и первой строк файлов

слияние последней строки одного файла и первой строки следующего файла при `cat [0-9][0-9].txt` происходит потому, что в конце файлов отсутствует символ [новой строки lf](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8).

исправить эту ситуацию прямо «на лету», не внося исправлений в сами файлы, можно, например, заменив `cat` на [`sed '$a\'`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31955/110559).

убедиться в действенности можно, например, сравнив конец шестнадцатиричной выдачи содержимого файла так:

```
$ cat файл | hexdump -C | tail -n 2
```

и так:

```
$ sed '$a\' файл | hexdump -C | tail -n 2
```

вы увидите, что во втором случае в конце файла появится символ с шестнадцатиричным кодом `0a` (он же *linefeed*, он же *lf*, он же «символ новой строки»).

кстати, и количество строк в таких файлах будет считаться (программой *wc*) неверно. поэтому я заменил выше все вызовы `cat` на `sed '$a\'`. для надёжности.

Comment: протестил, обнаружил проблему-
когда с помощью команды paste создается один файл, то в местах соединения файлов 01.txt-20.txt (между последней строкой и первой строкой следующего файла) не подставляется строка из файла big.txt, и последняя строка соединяется с первой строкой след. файла

Comment: т.к в комментах форматирование не позволяет корректно отобразить списки, то я добавил результат который у меня получается в сам топик выше

Comment: @Человексинтернета, я дополнил и исправил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь последняя команда, дает ошибку - $ eval "sed '$a\' newbig.txt $p >/dev/null"
sed: -e выражение #1, символ 1: незавершенное адресное регулярное выражение

Comment: @Человексинтернета, исправил упущение: в этой строке надо «заэскейпить» `$`, чтобы оболочка не пыталась разыменовать `$a` как переменную.

Comment: Работает спасибо, и последний вопрос, открывая готовый файл (в windows) я вижу что добавленная строка идет с новой строки, тоесть как будто между строкой из файла big.txt и 01.txt стоит перевод строки.  корректно (т.е целиком без переноса) отображается только самая последняя строка готового файла.

Comment: я делаю все это из UNIX-подобной среды  (интерфейс командной строки для Microsoft Windows) - Cygwin

Comment: @Человексинтернета, вероятно, последнее описанное вами происходит из-за чехарды с окончаниями строк — [в разных системах они разные](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8). боюсь, ничего дельного, помимо использования [dos2unix/unix2dos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) подсказать не смогу, т.к. *ms/windows* у меня нет (и в будущем не предвидится).

Comment: решил проблему так- через поиск и замена , заменил "\n;" на ";"

Comment: еще вопрос, названия файлов 01, 02 и тд. я привел для примера, на самом деле у меня названия файлов это словосочетания. т.к данную процедуру буду проводить часто и файлов будет более 20 то каждый раз переименовывать файлы не хочется. Как мне правильно заменить в вашем скрипте кусок "[0-9][0-9].txt" на названия моих файлов? И появляется еще проблема -  потом они все будут с приставкой "new". Можно ли сделать чтобы файлы перезаписывались например, чтобы потом не убирать из названия каждого файла слово "new"

Comment: @Человексинтернета *Как мне правильно заменить в вашем скрипте кусок "[0-9][0-9].txt" на названия моих файлов?* — укажите любую подходящую маску. проверяйте, попали ли под маску нужные файлы, и в том ли порядке они отображаются, например, командой `ls маска`. *потом они все будут с приставкой "new"* — проще помещать их в другой (существующий) каталог. замените `new$f` на `каталог/$f`.

Comment: поставил маску "[а-я]*.txt" - все файлы содержащие кирилицу